Create a regular n-gon from sides and bounds width
I am trying to create a regular polygon with an arbitrarily number of sides with the starting parameters:

number of sides,
width of bounding box.

And the polygon should have an edge at the base.
For the purpose of clarification I drawn what i expect as the result, in white:



Assume this inscribed polygons are regular and the rectangle bounding box is touching the outermost vertice(s) of the polygon

$$w=2r\sin{(2k+1)\pi\over n},$$ where $k$ is the integer nearest to $(n-2)/4$.

Solution:
Input:
Sides = integer larger than 3
Width = width of the bounding box

Algorithm:
CentralAngle = PI/sides * 2
CenterX = Width / 2
Radius = Width / (2 * Sin((2 * Round((Sides-2)/4) + 1) * CentralAngle / 2))
Aphotem = Radius * Cos(CentralAngle / 2))

If Sides are even:
 CenterY = Aphotem
 Height = Aphotem * 2
 If Sides are multiple of 4:
  StartAngle = CentralAngle / 2
 Otherwise:
  StartAngle = CentralAngle

If Sides are odd:      
 CenterY = Radius       
 StartAngle = -(3 * PI / 2) - CentralAngle / 2
 Height = Apothem + Radius

For each Vertice:
(VerticeIndex = 0 up to Sides-1)
 Angle = StartAngle + CentralAngle * VerticeIndex
 CoordinateX = CenterX + Radius * Cos(Angle)
 CoordinateY = CenterY + Radius * Sin(Angle)


Radius calculation with help from Intelligenti Pauca in the comment section
